Is there a name for "applying linear operations to vector sequences from the right"?
Let $v_1,...,v_n\in\Bbb R^d$ be a sequence of vectors. When we say that we "linearly transform" this sequence, we mean that we apply a linear transformation $T\in\Bbb R^{d\times d}$ to each vector in the sequence individually.
This can also be expressed as applying the transformations $T$ from the left to the following matrix, and then reading off the columns of the resulting matrix:
$$
\newcommand{\verts}{\rule{0.2pt}{1.3em}}
\Phi(\boldsymbol v):=\begin{bmatrix}
    \verts & \!\verts & & \verts \\[-1ex]
\,v_1 & \!v_2 & \!\!\!\cdots\!\!\! & v_n\, \\
    \verts & \!\verts & & \verts
\end{bmatrix}\in\Bbb R^{d\times n}
$$

Question: Is there an established name for what I am doing when I apply a linear transformation $S\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ from the right to this matrix and then read off the columns?
$$v_1,...,v_n \,\overset S\mapsto\, w_1,...,w_n,\quad \text{if}\,\; \Phi(\boldsymbol w)=\Phi(\boldsymbol v)S.$$

Examples of this are:

permuting the vectors in the sequence ($S$ is a permutation matrix).
scaling each vector individually ($S$ is a diagonal matrix).

Neither of this falls under "linearly transforming the sequence" with the usual meaning. But it is still linear in some sense, and I would like to have a suitable terminology to refer to these transformations.
I suppose these sort of transformations can be called column operations on $\Phi(\boldsymbol v)$, but I wonder specifically whether there is a name for the operations when we think of vector sequences and want to avoid thinking of matrices and explicit basis representations. I am mostly interested in the case when $S$ is invertible.

Can the downvoter explain his vote please.

Each $w_j$ is a linear combination of the $v_i$. Concretely if the entries in the $j$'th column of $S$ are $s_{1j}, \ldots s_{nj}$ then $w_j = s_{1j} v_1 + \ldots + s_{nj} v_n$. Taking a linear combination is a well known and well and well named operation on vector sequences; I thinks here you then would call it 'taking $n$ linear combinations of the $n$ vectors in the sequence'

(I'm not the downvoter btw, my comment was just an answer)

How about action on the left or right: You have a finite-dimensional vector space and you act on it on the left or right by its group of automorphisms.
